# Wrap node labels

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there any way to make node label text wrap? I have some nodes with very long labels, and they would be more readable if wrapped onto 2 or 3 lines. I tried using CSS but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2015, you can use `text-wrap`: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels

Comment: I'm trying to visualize the decision tree for tic tac toe. I would like to have the game board displayed as text labels. I know it's not great ui but it would really make things easier.